# Yii2 - migration, a foreign key constraint fails

Tags: php, model-view-controller, yii2, database-migration

I use migration, created up() like that:

```
$this->addColumn('presentation_place', 'user_id', $this->integer()->notNull()->after('post_code'));
$this->addForeignKey('fk_presentation_place_user_id', 'presentation_place', 'user_id', 'user', 'id', 'CASCADE', 'CASCADE');
```

And while yii/migrate I'm getting error

> Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails
>   ('crm'.'#sql-1524_46f', CONSTRAINT 'fk_presentation_place_user_id'
>   FOREIGN KEY ('user_id') REFERENCES 'user' ('id') ON DELETE CASCADE ON
>   UPDATE CASCADE)

I don't know what can be wrong, I've done migrations couple of times before, so I'm really surprised.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the error message I think that the foreign key add was successful, but you have rows in user and presentation_place.

Try running this migration with empty tables **or** set a default value which exists in the referenced table

```
defaultValue(ALREADY_EXISTING_ID)
```

Comment: Wow, I didn't believe it could work, but it really solved my problem. I mean defaultValue(). Thanks Zoltan! :)